# Collapsible panels not expanding after asynchronous update event inside a update panel?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap, asynchronous

I am developing website using ASP.net. I have a page where user enter his CV. So I am going to save the details into db in 1 min interval asynchronously like happen in email servers. ( drafts )

So I have collapsible panels for categorize user's data.

Below code is the panels

```
      <asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional" ID="uppnlVacancy">
  <div class="panel panel-primary">

            <ContentTemplate>
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    <h1 class="panel-title">Vacancy
              <asp:Literal runat="server" ID="litVacancy"></asp:Literal>
                    </h1>
                    <span class="pull-right clickable"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down"></i></span>
                </div>
                <div class="panel-body panel-collapse collapse">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-4">
                            <asp:Literal runat="server" Text="Designation"></asp:Literal>
                            <br />
                            <asp:DropDownList ID="ddDesignation" runat="server" Width="100%" CssClass="form-control">
                            </asp:DropDownList>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-4">
                            <asp:Literal runat="server" Text="Specialization"></asp:Literal>
                            <br />
                            <asp:DropDownList ID="ddSpecialization" runat="server" Width="100%" CssClass="form-control">
                            </asp:DropDownList>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <br />
                    <asp:Literal runat="server" Text="Expertise / Skills ( Use comma to separate )"></asp:Literal><br />
                    <asp:TextBox runat="server" TextMode="MultiLine" Rows="3" CssClass="form-control" ID="txtSkillSet"></asp:TextBox>
                </div>

    </div>
            </ContentTemplate>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

I am using below jquery to collpse and expand panels

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('.panel-heading span.clickable').addClass('panel-collapsed');
        });
    });

    jQuery(function ($) {
        $('.panel-heading span.clickable').on("click", function (e) {
            if ($(this).hasClass('panel-collapsed')) {
                // expand the panel
                $(this).parents('.panel').find('.panel-body').slideDown();
                $(this).removeClass('panel-collapsed');
                $(this).find('i').removeClass('glyphicon-chevron-down').addClass('glyphicon-chevron-up');
            }
            else {
                // collapse the panel
                $(this).parents('.panel').find('.panel-body').slideUp();
                $(this).addClass('panel-collapsed');
                $(this).find('i').removeClass('glyphicon-chevron-up').addClass('glyphicon-chevron-down');
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

So added a timer like this

```
<asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:Timer runat="server" Interval="3000" OnTick="Unnamed_Tick"></asp:Timer>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

In tick event I use this code

```
 protected void Unnamed_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ShowSummary();
            uppnlVacancy.Update();
        }
```

So above code works fine.litVacancy label update as expected. But after update happened collapsible not working. Label is still updating when I change the record in the DB.

So whats wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not super familiar with ASP.NET but if you are dynamically changing .panel-heading you probably should do this instead:

```
$("body").on("click",".panel-heading span.clickable", function (e) {
```

You may be modifying that DOM element enough that it's unbinding the click event.